# ¿Cómo calcular el valor de la derivada de una función en un punto de forma numérica en python?

Tags: python-3.x, calculo

Como dice la pregunta, deseo calcular el valor de una derivada en *Python*, he creado un código que en teoría debería de hacerlo a través de la definición de la derivada sin embargo, cuando el programa va haciendo los cálculos en un `ciclo for` haciendo las veces de límite, el valor de la derivada da 0 a partir como de la 28ava o 26ava  iteración, estoy utilizando 30 iteraciones en donde en teoría me voy aproximando al valor real; Sé que hay librerías para ello pero quiero hacerlo de forma más manual.
PD:la única librería que defino es la de math.

Este es el código

```
import math
n=30
x=0.5
h=1
emax=0
for i in range(1,30):
    h=0.25*h
    u=(float(math.asin(x+h)-math.asin(x))/float(h))
    error=math.fabs((math.acos(x)-u))
    if error>emax:
        emax=error
        imax=i
print("Y=",u, "error máximo=",emax)
```

Comment: Calcular la derivada de forma numérica causa problemas complicados debido a cómo funciona el punto flotante. Para detalles mira aqui https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Floating-point_finite_differences En tu caso, tras 30 iteraciones en las que divides h por 4 (2^-2) en cada iteración llegarías a un valor de 2^-60, no representable en precisión doble, sino sólo en forma desnormalizada. Aunque en esa forma no se redondea a cero (por eso puedes dividir por h), sí se convertírá en 0 al sumarlo a x, pues éste no está desnormalizado.

Comment: Oh entiendo, muchísimas gracias de verdad, estaré investigando más sobre el funcionamiento de punto flotante

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explicación breve

Los ordenadores no pueden almacenar números arbitrariamente grandes, ni tampoco arbitrariamente pequeños.

En tu código, al multiplicar `h*0.25` una y otra vez, llega un momento en que `h` es tan pequeño que empezará a causar errores de redondeo.

Por otro lado, no es necesario iterar para ir reduciendo `h`. Simplemente debes elegir un valor adecuado para `h` (y ahí está la dificultad) y usarlo una sola vez para obtener la estimación de la derivada. El problema es que si usas una `h` demasiado pequeña, tendrás errores de redondeo (como se explica en [este artículo de wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Floating-point_finite_differences)), pero si usas una `h` demasiado grande, los puntos de la curva que estás tomando darán una secante que puede que ya no sea una buena aproximación de la tangente.

Encontrar el `h` apropiado tiene su dificultad (mira de nuevo el enlace a Wikipedia), por lo que es mejor usar librerías que hagan el trabajo por tí y que ya han tenido en cuenta todas las sutilezas de los problemas de punto flotante.

## Explicación larga

El estándar de representación de números reales IEEE-754 de precisión doble (que es el usado por Python) almacena cada número en 64 bits. Ya te puedes dar cuenta de que con 64 bits hay para almacenar 2**64 números diferentes. Son muchos, pero no son infinitos, por lo que habrá necesariamente números no representables, tanto porque sean demasiado grandes como porque tengan demasiados decimales.

En particular, en esos 64 bits se usan 11 de ellos para almacenar un exponente y otros 52 para almacenar dígitos binarios, llamados la Mantisa (el bit que falta es para el signo).

Si la secuencia de bits guardada en la mantisa es M (por ejemplo M="00101010000...000") y la secuencia de bits guardada en el exponente, la convertimos a base 10 y nos sale el número E (por ejemplo E=19), entonces el número representado por esa combinación sería:

```
1.M * 2**(E-1023)
```

Entendiendo que la parte `1.M` está en binario (en el ejemplo sería `1.00101010000...000` mientras que el resto de la fórmula está en decimal.

Un ejemplo. La mantisa contiene el primer bit 1 y el resto ceros (M="10000...000") y el exponente contiene `10000000000` que es el número 1024 una vez convertido a base 10. Entonces el número codificado de esta forma será:

```
1.1000000000..000 * 2**(1024-1023)
```

Es decir 1.1 (binario) por 2 elevado a 1. El 1.1 binario representa al 1.5 en decimal, y ya que está multiplicado por 2, el número finalmente sería el 3.0

Como ves, dependiendo de cuántos decimales (binarios) tenga el número que pretendes representar, si no caben en los 52 que este formato tiene para la mantisa, se descartarán los que no quepan, y se estará cometiendo entonces un error (que en error absoluto depende de la cantidad codificada en el exponente, lo que significa entonces que cometes mayor error cuanto mayor sea el número a representar, lo que está bien porque entonces el error relativo se mantiene constante).

Te habrás fijado que para decodificar se pone un 1 delante de la mantisa, por lo que el número más pequeño que podría codificarse, de acuerdo con lo dicho, sería en principio el formado por una mantisa todo ceros, y un exponente todo ceros, que sería el `1.0 * 2**(-1023)`. ¿Cómo representar entonces el cero?

Lo cierto es que cuando el valor almacenado en el campo exponente es 0000000000000 (once ceros), eso se decodifica de forma especial. Ya no se considera la fórmula antes vista, sino que se usa otra así:

```
0.M * 2**(-1022)
```

y estos se llaman número "denormalizados". En vez de añadir un `1.` por delante de la mantisa, se añade un `0.`, y el E ya no se tiene en cuenta y se considera un exponente fijo de -1022. Esto permite representar al 0 como un caso en que la mantisa es todo ceros (52 ceros) y el exponente también todo ceros (para indicar que es denormalizado).

También permite codificar números más pequeños de 2**(-1023), gracias a que podemos tener una mantisa que sea 00000..0000001 (un 1 al final del todo y el resto ceros), por lo que eso codificaría la cantidad minúscula 0.00000....00001 * 2**(-1022), es decir, 2**(-1022-52) = 2**(-1074)

Y, ese sí, es el menor positivo representable en este formato. Es decir, los números cercanos a cero se pueden representar con mucha mayor precisión que ningún otro número. Pero si sumas un número tan pequeño como ese a otro que no sea "denormal", ya que el resultado no será "denormal", se perderán todos los bits extra que el número denormal tenía.

Es decir, para una `h` suficientemente pequeña, aunque se cumpliría que `h != 0.0`  sin embargo ocurrirá que `x+h == x`

Mira esta mini **demo**:

```
>>> x = 1.0
>>> a = 2**-1060
>>> x == x + a
True
>>> x == x - a
True
>>> a == 0
False
>>> a
8.095e-320
```

¡Sorpresas del punto flotante cuando se trabaja en el límite!

### Añadido

En realidad no hace falta llegar a tener números denormalizados para que `x+h=x`. Basta con que el resultado de la operación no quepa en los 52 bits de la mantisa.

Si por ejemplo a la cantidad `1.0` le queremos sumar 2**-53 (que en binario sería 0.0000....0001, habiendo 52 ceros entre el punto decimal y el 1 final), tendremos que el resultado sería `1.0000...0001` (de nuevo con 52 ceros). Es decir, la mantisa de este resultado requerirá 53 bits y como eso no cabe en los 52 que usa el formato IEEE, se despreciará el último bit y el resultado será 1.0000...000 (52 ceros). Es decir, sale 1 otra vez, como si no le hubiéramos sumado nada.

Es por esto que en tu caso para cuando `h` alcanza el valor 2**-64 (lo que ocurre en la 16ª iteración), aunque ese valor no es cero, la derivada sí que te sale cero, porque `x+h` es `x`, y por tanto `f(x+h)` te saldrá igual a `f(x)`, no importa cuál sea la función `f()` que estés derivando.

Comment: ¡Infinitas gracias!, tienes un conocimiento muy amplio y te sabes explicar excelente, ahora entiendo las dificultades de trabajar en computación cosas como derivadas e integrales, curioso como el punto flotante afecta en estos conceptos matemáticos, de nuevo, muchas gracias :D.

Answer (score 5):

Nota 1:
Formalmente hablando, no estás usando la definición, sino la aproximación por incrementos. En este método, el parámetro `h` es fijo, mientras que tu programa lo actualiza en cada bucle `for`, como tienes valores más exactos de la derivada según `h` disminuye, estás cambiando la precisión en cada punto donde la evaluas, podrías tomar el valor de `h` final directamente si lo que te interesa es calcular derivadas.

Nota 2:
La función arcoseno no tiene de derivada arcocoseno, sino `1/(1-x**2)**0.5`

Solución:
No he utilizado nunca math, uso numpy y obtengo la misma respuesta, también si lo hago con una calculadora de mano. Creo que la cuestión reside en la precisión, llega un momento en que `h` es tan pequeño que la variación en el arcoseno es más pequeña que la precisión que puede darte la función, quiero decir: `math.asin(0.5)` devuelve `0.5235987755982989` y `math.sin(0.5+h*0.25**30)` también, es quizás porque el cambio está en unas cifras decimales que no se presentan (un ordenador no puede tener precisión infinita), por lo que, al restar da cero.

Comment: Desconozco si el razonamiento matematico es correcto (o no lo recuerdo) y por eso no tenes mi voto positivo (no puedo votar algo que no se si esta bien o mal), pero que bien respondida que esta.

Answer (score 0):

Hola a quien sea que vea mi pregunta

Aquí se explicó por qué mi algoritmo no funcionaba y cómo bien se dijo era por causa de cómo la maquina procesaba los números y las limitaciones que esta tiene al trabajar en el campo numérico, sin embargo, si alguien está interesado en saber como se puede calcular una derivada de forma numérica lo que puede hacer es recurrir a las formulas de diferencias finitas que se estudian en cursos de métodos numéricos, estas formulas lo que hacen es aproximar la derivada de una función en un punto y se llegan a resultados muy aproximados, incluso si se quiere mejorar la aproximación de estas derivadas se puede utilizar la extrapolación de richardson que se apoya en las formulas de diferencias finitas para mejorar el resultado. A continuación adjunto un código en donde se ejemplifica el uso de estas formulas

```
import math as m
f={1:lambda x: x**2+2*x+1,2:lambda x: m.sin(x),3:lambda x: m.exp(2*x),4:lambda x:m.cosh(x)+m.tanh(x)} #listado de funciones
derivadas={1:lambda x:2*x+2,2:lambda x:m.cos(x),3:lambda x: 2*m.exp(2*x),4:lambda x: m.sinh(x)+1/m.cosh(x)**2} #listado de derivadas de las funciones
def FiniteDiferencies(id): #función para calcular las diferencias finitas
    xi=0 #valor de la derivada a evaluar
    h=0.1 #tamaño de paso
    dfa=(f[id](xi)-f[id](xi-h))/h #aproximación hacia atrás
    dfc=(f[id](xi+h)-f[id](xi-h))/(2*h) #aproximación centrada
    dfad=(f[id](xi+h)-f[id](xi))/h #apriximación hacia adelante
    return dfa,dfc,dfad,derivadas[id](xi) #retorna los resultados en forma de tupla
def RichardsonExtrapolation(id,dfa,dfc,dfad):
    xi=0 #valor de la derivada a evaluar
    h=0.1/2 #tamaño de paso
    dfa2=(f[id](xi)-f[id](xi-h))/h #aproximación hacia atrás
    dfc2=(f[id](xi+h)-f[id](xi-h))/(2*h) #aproximación centrada
    dfad2=(f[id](xi+h)-f[id](xi))/h #apriximación hacia adelanta
    D1=dfa2+1/((1e-5/h)**2-1)*(dfa2-dfa) #extrapolación de richardson para la derivada hacia atrás
    D2=dfc2+1/((1e-5/h)**2-1)*(dfc2-dfc) #extrapolación de richardson para la derivada centrada
    D3=dfad2+1/((1e-5/h)**2-1)*(dfad2-dfad)#extrapolación de Richardson para la derivada hacia adelante
    return D1,D2,D3 #retorna los resultados en forma de tupla
id=int(input("Elige la función: ")) #se escribe la función por consola
result=FiniteDiferencies(id) #se llama a la función con el id de la función a trabajar y a buscar en el diccionario
result2=RichardsonExtrapolation(id,result[0],result[1],result[2])
#se muestran los resultados calculados con diferencias finitas
print("Aproximación hacia atrás de la derivada de la función elegida en el punto elegido a través de diferencias finitas",result[0])
print("Aproximación central de la derivada de la función elegida en el punto elegido a través de diferencias finitas ",result[1])
print("Aproximación hacia adelante de la derivada de la función elegida en el punto elegido a través de diferencias finitas ",result[2])
print("Valor de la derivada real ",result[3])
#se muestran los resultados calculados con la extrapolación de richardson
print("Resultados con la extrapolación de richardson")
print("Aproximación hacia atrás de la derivada de la función elegida en el punto elegido a través de extrapolación de Richardson",result2[0])
print("Aproximación central de la derivada de la función elegida en el punto elegido a través de extrapolación de Richardson ",result2[1])
print("Aproximación hacia adelante de la derivada de la función elegida en el punto elegido a través de extrapolación de Richardson ",result2[2])
print("Valor de la derivada real ",result[3])
```